# .click function is triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is only supposed to run when the Register button is clicked but instead it's adding it below the login page. Once Register is clicked though it goes to Register layout and when you click back on log in, it is the correct log in layout.
How can I stop it from doing this?

```
$(function() {
    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: can we see a codepen or something ?  your code is fine

Comment: You need to describe problem better and put more code if you want to get better responses

Comment: your code is fine you can instead put it in function and call the function  `onclick`